# Hibernate - Custom insert into database

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I write this post to know if someone knows how to do this:

I want to do this insert:

```
INSERT INTO TABLA (CAMPO1, CAMPO2) VALUES (?, crypt(?,'cdp'))
```

Crypt is a function stored in my database and the insert I would want to do it in my code. Actually when I want to insert something in the database I use:

```
getHibernateTemplate().persist(obj);
```

But I want to do a "custom" insert, because I need to use that function.

I am using hibernate + annotations:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.SQLInsert (sql = "INSERT INTO TABLA (CAMPO1, CAMPO2) VALUES (?, crypt(?,'cdp'))")
```

But the key 'cdp' must be readed from a file, so this solution doesn't work for me.

I want to use a method on my code to execute a SQL query (INSERT query)

Comment: Is this doable using raw SQL (in other words, let's put Hibernate aside)? If yes, I don't understand why the `@SQLInsert` doesn't work for you. If not, I'm afraid Hibernate won't help. Can you clarify?

Comment: Doesn't work for me because I need to get a String with the cryption key, so I don't know how to introduce it on the @SQLInsert

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO TABLA (CAMPO1, CAMPO2) VALUES (:valor1, encripta(:valor2, :key))");
query.setParameter("valor1", valor1);
query.setParameter("valor2", valor2);
query.setParameter("key", key);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: you should not be in the habbit of doing string appends to your sql statements.  Better to use named parameters.

Comment: @NathanFeger your point is important enough that I edited this answer to incorporate it

Comment: Is there a way to get the generate keys [as in JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4224729/1652461) ?

Answer (score 19):

Like Nathan Feger mentioned, named parameters are much cleaner and safer. In this case, the statement can be executed with the following code:

```
Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO TABLA (CAMPO1, CAMPO2) VALUES (:valor1, encripta(:valor2, :key))");
query.setParameter("valor1", valor1);
query.setParameter("valor2", valor2);
query.setParameter("key", key);
query.executeUpdate();
```