# PreparedStatement with Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS

Tags: java, jdbc

The only way that some JDBC drivers to return `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` is to do something of the following:

```
long key = -1L;
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate(YOUR_SQL_HERE, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
    key = rs.getLong(1);
}
```

Is there a way to do the same with `PreparedStatement`?

---

**Edit**

The reason I asked if I can do the same with `PreparedStatement` consider the following scenario:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE = 
            "INSERT INTO
            USER(FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL_ADDRESS, DOB) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

In the `USER` table there's a `PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)` which is a `BIGINT AUTOINCREMENT` (hence why you don't see it in the `SQL_CREATE` String.

Now, I populate the `?` using `PreparedStatement.setXXXX(index, value)`. I want to return `ResultSet rs = PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Many people misunderstand and use PreparedStatement#executeUpdate(arg) . Java doc says `This method with argument cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement.` It means we have to use executeUpdate() without argument even though `executeUpdate(arg)` method can be inherited in PreparedStatement class but we don't have to use it otherwise we will get SQLException.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can either use the `prepareStatement` method taking an additional `int` parameter

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)
```

For some JDBC drivers (for example, Oracle) you have to explicitly list the column names or indices of the generated keys:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql, new String[]{"USER_ID"})
```

Comment: I've accepted your answer as you've showed more ways to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 73):

You mean something like this?

```
long key = -1L;

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(YOUR_SQL_HERE, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
preparedStatement.setXXX(index, VALUE);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();

if (rs.next()) {
    key = rs.getLong(1);
}
```

Comment: How can the generated keys result set be null?

Answer (score 11):

Not having a compiler by me right now, I'll answer by asking a question:

Have you tried this? Does it work?

```
long key = -1L;
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement();
statement.executeUpdate(YOUR_SQL_HERE, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
    key = rs.getLong(1);
}
```

Disclaimer: Obviously, I haven't compiled this, but you get the idea.

[PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) is a subinterface of [Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html), so I don't see a reason why this wouldn't work, unless some JDBC drivers are buggy.

Comment: that's not what I'm looking for I know that `PreparedStatement` is a subclass of `Statement`....see my updated post.

Answer (score 5):

```
String query = "INSERT INTO ....";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

preparedStatement.setXXX(1, VALUE); 
preparedStatement.setXXX(2, VALUE); 
....
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();  

ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();  
int key = rs.next() ? rs.getInt(1) : 0;

if(key!=0){
    System.out.println("Generated key="+key);
}
```

Comment: If key generated then key otherwise key=0 if not generated

Answer (score 0):

```
private void alarmEventInsert(DriveDetail driveDetail, String vehicleRegNo, int organizationId) {

    final String ALARM_EVENT_INS_SQL = "INSERT INTO alarm_event (event_code,param1,param2,org_id,created_time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    CachedConnection conn = JDatabaseManager.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet generatedKeys = null;
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(ALARM_EVENT_INS_SQL, ps.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setInt(1, driveDetail.getEventCode());
        ps.setString(2, vehicleRegNo);
        ps.setString(3, null);
        ps.setInt(4, organizationId);
        ps.setString(5, driveDetail.getCreateTime());
        ps.execute();
        generatedKeys = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (generatedKeys.next()) {
            driveDetail.setStopDuration(generatedKeys.getInt(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Error inserting into alarm_event : {}", e
                .getMessage());
        logger.info(ps.toString());
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            try {

                if (ps != null)
                    ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error closing prepared statements : {}", e
                        .getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    JDatabaseManager.freeConnection(conn);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be freeing your connection in the finally block, not outside it (you'll leek a connection if you get a runtime exception of any kind)?

Comment: @niraj - instead of ps.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS we can write Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS because it is static variable in the java.sql.Statement class.