# SQLException - Generated keys not requested (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql

I get this error when im making a new character to my game, in the CreateCharHandler it sends "saveToDb(false);" but when im ingame with another char i manually created i can saveToDb(true); with no error. please help, why is this happening?

http://i56.tinypic.com/oh1pn5.png

SaveToDb method http://pastebin.com/9sT5XBxp

line 3514 is:

```
ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Charlie, since outside links tend to decay and disappear (especially pastebin) it is better to include the code and the pictures you want to show directly in your question.  You can do so by clicking edit right above the comment box.

Answer (score 48):

Your `SQLException` clearly states that:

> You need to specify `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` to the
>   `Statement.executeUpdate()` or `Connection.prepareStatement()`.

This can be achieved as follows (adding an additional value on `Connection.prepareStatement()` method):

```
String SQL = ""; //whatever my String is
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ps.setString(1, "value");
//Other necessary ps.setXXX() methods

//now update
ps.executeUpdate();

ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
```

The `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` is key here.

Hope this helps!

PS: [Useful resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224228/preparedstatement-with-statement-return-generated-keys).

---

@Charlie berg, since you prefer being lazy, I changed line 13 of your code to include the `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`:

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO characters (level, fame, str, dex, luk, `int`, exp, hp, mp, maxhp, maxmp, sp, ap, gm, skincolor, gender, job, hair, face, map, meso, hpMpUsed, spawnpoint, party, buddyCapacity, messengerid, messengerposition, mountlevel, mounttiredness, mountexp, equipslots, useslots, setupslots, etcslots, monsterbookcover, watchedcygnusintro, vanquisherStage, dojopoints, lastDojoStage, finishedDojoTutorial, vanquisherKills, matchcardwins, matchcardlosses, matchcardties, omokwins, omoklosses, omokties, givenRiceCakes, partyquestitems, jailtime, accountid, name, world) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Also, `Statement` class is of package `java.sql` (make sure you import correctly). :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help!

But unlucky i dont understand -facepalm- could you please show me what to change in my codes and ill promise i'll learn :D. Tyty

Comment: @Charlie berg, just change line 13 to this (See how I just added the `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` to your `con.prepareStatement`.

Answer (score 4):

[Oracle Documents](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/crefjavstateautogen.html):

> If there is no indication that auto-generated columns should be made
>   available for retrieval, a call to Statement.getGeneratedKeys will
>   return a null ResultSet.

You should explicitly tell to JDBC That you want generated keys.

like this:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

or

```
conn.prepareStatement(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

and then you can use `getGeneratedKeys()`.