# Retrieving the last inserted Identity ID from a table using the Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS routine?

Tags: java, jdbc, javadb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc)

In the following statement, how can I fetch the last inserted C12 identity value? This is from the JavaDB manual, but they have not mentioned how to retrieve this last inserted value from this record set.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (C11 int, C12 int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY)

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
stmt.execute(
    "INSERT INTO TABLE1 (C11) VALUES (1)",
    Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example to get generated keys:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
    key = rs.getLong(1);
}
```

PS: A related [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224228/preparedstatement-with-statement-return-generated-keys) can suffice.

Comment: It never returns `null`.

Comment: Fair enough! :-) it's old habit.

Comment: @BalusC : Only if the driver is implemented properly, otherwise it might return null :) BTW: if rs.getLong(1) returns the actual key depends on how the JDBC driver is implemented: some databases will return *all* columns when using RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS (eg PostgreSQL does)

Comment: @Mark: that would violate the javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29 The `ResultSet` has either a key or is empty. Or a `SQLException` will be thrown.

Comment: The javadoc can claim a lot, but if the driver implementer didn't read it properly it can return null (I know because I recently fixed exactly such a bug in Jaybird). Especially as the similar getResultSet() method *can* return null.