# Can I SELECT with LAST_INSERT_ID() after INSERT Batch without any cares?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm asking myself if it is possible to `SELECT` with `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in `WHERE` Clause after an batch of `INSERT`s without getting corrupt data in the tables? I'm thinking of the scenario that multiple users doing the same stuff at the same time. I develop an JSF Application in which this scenario can be possible.

In hard Code my `SELECT` after `INSERT`s looks like this:

```
preparedstatement.addBatch(
              "INSERT INTO table1(all the FIELDS)"
              + "VALUES(null, ...);"
      );

      preparedstatement.addBatch(
              "INSERT INTO table2(all the FIELDS)"
              + "VALUES(null, LAST_INSERT_ID(), ...);"          
      );


      preparedstatement = connect.prepareStatement(

              "SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();"

      );

      preparedstatement.executeBatch();
      resultSet = preparedstatement.executeQuery();
```

Get I problems with this implementation or is there an better way?

Best Regards

Comment: Have a look at this page ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224228/preparedstatement-with-statement-return-generated-keys

Comment: The only thing i saw on this page is to get the Keys from a `connect.preparedStatement()` but in my case i need to get the keys from a batch.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question... See the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine, quoting MySQL's documentation:

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
>   **per-connection basis**. This means that the value returned by the
>   function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated
>   for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that
>   client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they
>   generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures
>   that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the
>   activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or
>   transactions.

[MySQL Last_insert_id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)