# How to get the ID of auto generated id from the Database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc)

I have the following tables:

`customer(cid, ...)`

`book(cid, rid)`

`reservation(rid, ...)`

I want to add a reservation in its table then I want to add in a relationship in `book` between `customer` and `reservation`.

How can I know `rid` while it is auto generated, and when I execute the query I did get a `ResultSet` returned?

The `rid` is auto generated form Oracle using a sequence and a trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to your question I believe you are using statements. In this case, you can use `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`. Also please consider this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4224729/706695) as below solution can have conficts for Oracle database.

Here is small example:

```
Connection connection = database.getConnection();
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(myQuery, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
int count = statement.executeUpdate();
if(count <= 0){
 //value not inserted
}

ResultSet results = statement.getGeneratedKeys();

if(results.next){
 System.out.println(generatedKeys.getLong(1));
}
```

in case of you are using ORM:

If you are using JPA   `entitiyManager.merge(entity);` (or update) should return persisted instance with ID. 
Quite similar with hibernate `session.merge(entity);` (or update)

Answer (score 1):

Dunno how it is with java/jsp, but if it's a relational DB, you'd have to use a set of queries - i.e. get the one id you do know (cid) and then get the rid from the book table. There's no other way I know of.

Hope that helps.