# How to get the auto-generated value from database when inserting new record?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have table with columns *id, name, address, city, state, zip*. Here *id* is auto generated when inserting new record like this: `insert into table1(name,address,city,state,zip) values(?,?,?,?,?)`.

Here's my code:

```
preparedstatement.setString(1,name);
preparedstatement.setString(2,address);
preparedstatement.setString(3,city);
preparedstatement.setString(4,state);
preparedstatement.setString(5,zip);

preparedstatement.executeUpdate();
```

Now I want to know what is the `id` value which was generated automatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the prepared statement with the additional flag `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` and make use of [`PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29):

```
String sql = "insert into table1(name,address,city,state,zip) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement preparedstatement
= con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

//....

preparedstatement.setString(1,name);
preparedstatement.setString(2,address);
preparedstatement.setString(3,city);
preparedstatement.setString(4,state);
preparedstatement.setString(5,zip);

preparedstatement.executeUpdate();

ResultSet generatedKeys = preparedstatement.getGeneratedKeys();
//....
```

Related: [PreparedStatement with Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4224228/1175253)

Answer (score 3):

```
String query = <your query>;

PreparedStatement preparedstatement= 
       con.prepareStatement(query ,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)

preparedstatement.setString(1,name);
preparedstatement.setString(2,address);
preparedstatement.setString(3,city);
preparedstatement.setString(4,state);
preparedstatement.setString(5,zip);
```

And after the execute update ,

```
ResultSet rs = preparedstatement.getGeneratedKeys();
```

Try this.

Comment: Is this only way to get id value ? is there any functions to response when inserting the record ?