# ERROR: column "new" of relation xyz does not exist in postgresql Trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to generate a code for column `tpl_league_code` using a trigger after insert into the `tpl_league_tbl` table. New entry is inserted first and then the update should occur but I get an error saying column `new` of relation `tpl_league_tbl` doesn't exist.

**Here is my function script**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createLeagueCode()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  leagueCode character varying(25);
BEGIN
  leagueCode := 'LEAUGECODE'||(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tpl_league_tbl)||
(SELECT CAST (NOW() AS CHARACTER VARYING(10)));
  UPDATE tpl_league_tbl SET new.tpl_league_code=leagueCode;
  RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

**This is my trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER createLeagueTrigger
AFTER INSERT
ON tpl_league_tbl
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE createLeagueCode();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UPDATE` statement cannot work because table `tpl_league_tbl` does not have a column `new`. You would have to omit the `new.`.

But you should not do this in an`AFTER` trigger, you should do it in a `BEFORE` trigger like this:

```
NEW.tpl_league_code := leagueCode;
```

Then when you `RETURN NEW;`, the new row has been modified *before* it is inserted, which is what you want. It is cumbersome and expensive to insert a row only to update it a split second later.

Another thing: You should *not* run

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tpl_league_tbl;
```

inside the trigger function, because this is a very expensive operation that requires a sequential table scan.

If you need a random, unique suffix for `leagueCode`, I recommend that you use a sequence and get the number with `nextval`. That will be *much* cheaper.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am using hibernate to insert into the table.is there a way to achieve this in hibernate ?

Comment: Huh? That has nothing to do with Hibernate, it's all inside the database.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a trigger for such a simple task. It's overkill. Just create a sequence and use it instead of using `count`. Something like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE league_code START 1;

INSERT INTO tpl_league_tbl (..., leagueCode)
VALUES (..., 'LEAUGECODE' || nextval('league_code') || now()::varchar(10))
```

Comment: i am using hibernate to insert into tables,is there any way to achieve this in hibernate?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Hibernate, but I'm pretty sure it supports a lot of things, and if not you could always use a raw query like this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707098/hibernate-custom-insert-into-database